# what does htop stand for in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, top

Can someone please explain to me what `htop` mean? or refer me to a resource that explains it NOT tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 6):

`htop` means “Hisham’s `top`”, and Hisham is Hisham H. Muhammad, `htop`’s author. See [the FAQ](http://hisham.hm/htop/index.php?page=faq):

> **What does the 'h' in 'htop' stand for?**
>
> Well, the short explanation is a little obvious: the "h" stands for "Hisham", my name. :)
>
> The long explanation is that what inspired me to write htop was [pinfo](https://github.com/baszoetekouw/pinfo), an improved man and info reader that adds lots of features (in my machines 'man' is an alias to 'pinfo -m'). It was written by a guy called Przemek Borys. Since 'pinfo' was "a better info" and he named it "pinfo" ("Przemek's Info"), I decided to try to make "a better top" so I called it "htop" ("Hisham's top"). So yes, it is after my own name, but it's also a homage to another nice piece of software!